# SQL_ Extract failure/restoral events per user only if they are consecutive

Tags: sql, datetime, google-bigquery

I have a table for certain failure and restore events for users. I would like to find time difference between failure and restore event of every user.
Also for some failure events, there are multiple restore events, I want to find time diff only between consecutive ones.
And, there might be multiple failures before restores. I only want difference between consecutive failure and restore (ignoring all leading and trailing extra events for that user)

```
sr  imei            time                                event_type  
1    1              2020-01-01 14:28:06.269000+00:00    failure 
2    1              2020-01-01 14:28:29.910000+00:00    failure_restored    
3    5              2020-01-01 15:24:52.714000+00:00    failure 
4    5              2020-01-01 15:29:59.045000+00:00    failure_restored    
5    6              2020-01-01 21:21:32.715000+00:00    failure_restored    
6    7              2020-01-01 21:48:43.798000+00:00    failure_restored    
7    9              2020-01-01 22:18:34.112000+00:00    failure_restored    
8    9              2020-01-01 22:20:16.165000+00:00    failure 
9    9              2020-01-01 22:25:29.648000+00:00    failure_restored
```

I want to find time diff between failure/failure_restored events for every imei.
for eg:  between row 1 and 2, 3 and 4, row 6, 7 and 8 should be ignored and between row 8 and 9.

I could achieve it with pandas with custom made functions but need help with doing it in SQL.

Comment: Please tag database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't specify what to do if there are two "failure"s in a row.  If you *always* know that the next row is a restore, then:

```
SELECT imei, TIMESTAMP_DIFF(next_time, time, MILLISECOND) as time_diff_in_milliseconds
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             LEAD(time) OVER (PARTITION BY imei ORDER BY time) as next_time
      FROM t
     )
WHERE event_type = 'failure';
```

If not, then check the next event type as well:

```
SELECT imei, TIMESTAMP_DIFF(next_time, time, MILLISECOND) as time_diff_in_milliseconds
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             LEAD(time) OVER (PARTITION BY imei ORDER BY time) as next_time,
             LEAD(event_type) OVER (PARTITION BY imei ORDER BY time) as next_event_type
      FROM t
     )
WHERE event_type = 'failure' and next_event_type = 'failure-restored';
```

Comment: Thanks. These helped a lot. I wasnt very much aware of the LEAD func here.

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT imei, TIMESTAMP_DIFF(restore_time, time, MILLISECOND) time_diff_in_milliseconds
FROM (
  SELECT *, LEAD(IF(event_type = 'failure_restored', time, NULL)) OVER(PARTITION BY imei ORDER BY time) restore_time
  FROM `project.dataset.table`  
)
WHERE event_type = 'failure'
```

if to apply to sample data from your question - result is

```
Row imei    time_diff_in_milliseconds    
1   1       23641    
2   5       306331   
3   9       313483
```

Comment: have you tried? i think my answer does exactly that!

Comment: getting total timediff is not something I wanted, I wanted to see timediff for each instance of failure and restored.

Comment: i can only say that this is exactly what my answer does!